# MsSql express export from local pc to RDS, how to transfer NDF/LDF files?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

First time mssql admin here. Never worked with mssql before I might asked question improperly.
Couldn't find any posts mentioning ndf/ldf files import to AWS RDS mssql database.

Is data from these files included in mssql backup or we need to import NDF/LDF files separately?
We are using latest Express db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convention is that ndf is used for the 2nd & subsequent data file & ldf for the transaction log file - so YES these are included in your database backup. Also worth noting that these are just conventions and you can give the files any extension you like.

Comment: I understand from your answer that when I import mssql backup to RDS, I should just import backup file and I should be fine. Correct?

Comment: Correct - with the proviso that I don't know what RDS supports yet, if they have file limitations - nothing mentioned - see their docs here :-

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: Thank you, I would wait a few days and will mark your answer as THE answer :)